# VB.NET / SQL Server : how to reformat query data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have this data from a query: [Table](http://gyazo.com/f6617014c0700ffe4163e6c231e40210)

The data needs to be arranged differently, like this...

```
   Subjects   |   Predicted     |   Achieved
   ----------------------------------------------
   Art                 B                6
   Drama               B                6
```

I just can't work out how to reformat the data.

I'm using Visual Studio with vb.net and the data will need to be put into a datagrid. The version of SQL Server I'm using is 2008.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: please put the relevant code, including SQL in the question.

Comment: Looks like what you want is a `PIVOT` operation.